# Replace substring not inside HTML tag

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var token = "test123123{parent-area-identifier}<span data-tokenval='{=percent?metricType=1&area={parent-area-identifier}&with=E92000001&period=cal_2012}' class='mceNonEditable'>{=percent?metricType=1&area={parent-area-identifier}&with=E92000001&period=cal_2012}<span class='removetoken' href='javascript:;'>X</span></span>"
```

in the token string above, I want to replace `"{parent-area-identifier}"`, but NOT the string matching inside the `<span>` tag

So, if I replace it with `"ZZZ"`, the output should be:
`"test123123 ZZZ<span data-tokenval='{=percent?metricType=1&area={parent-area-identifier}&with=E92000001&period=cal_2012}' class='mceNonEditable'>{=percent?metricType=1&area={parent-area-identifier}&with=E92000001&period=cal_2012}<span class='removetoken' href='javascript:;'>X</span></span>"`.

Comment: Please reformat your question to make it more readable. It's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: formatted the question and made it simpler.

Comment: When you post a question, always include what you've tried so far. What regex have you used?

Comment: var strRegExp = new RegExp(/[{](?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}]/g); 
var strRegExpFunction = new RegExp(/[{]=(?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}]/g);

Answer (score 0):

```
token.replace(/{parent\-area\-identifier}/, "ZZZ")
```

This will match the first occurrence of {parent-area-identifier} and replace it with the "ZZZ" string. Note that the backward slashes are there to escape the dash character.

Comment: It can have multiple {parent-area-identifier} inside the string, so when I use /g, it replaces the tokens inside the `<span>` tags

Comment: Oh, so you mean your token can have multiple `{parent-area-indetifier}` outside the span?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. So basically I'm looking for a regex which can replace all these tokens, EXCEPT the ones inside `<span>` tag

Comment: Use `/(?:[^=])({parent\-area\-identifier})/` then?

Comment: Small fix: `token.replace(/([^=]){parent\-area\-identifier}/, "$1ZZZ")`, since JS doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: I figured it out, its: (?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)([{](?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}])

Comment: Now,the problem is replacing these regex tokens, excluding HTML.

Comment: Sorry, (?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)([{](?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}])  isn't working.